# Issue with Xamarin.Google.Guava

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, guava

I think I understand the error but I have no idea how to solve it :/

This is the error I'm getting:

"JAR library references with identical file names but different contents were found: __reference__guava.jar. Please remove any conflicting libraries from EmbeddedJar, InputJar and AndroidJavaLibrary. Food_Recipe_App.Android"

Reason to why I want Xamarin.Google.Guava is that someone said that it would fix an issue I had earlier;

"System.NullReferenceException
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Which, honestly, I have no idea how to solve either.

I'm thankful for all help :)

Edit: It breaks after calling the Firestore.Read();

```
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            //using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
            //{
            //    conn.CreateTable<Recipe>();
            //    var recipes = conn.Table<Recipe>().ToList();
            //    //recipeListView.ItemsSource = recipes;
            //};

            var recipes = await Firestore.Read(); ***//this line breaks***
            //assignRecipesToDays(recipes);
        }
```

This is the Read method from my Firestore script:

```
        public async Task<List<Recipe>> Read()
        {
            try
            {
                hasReadRecipes = false;
                var collection = FirebaseFirestore.Instance.Collection("recipes");

                var query = collection.WhereEqualTo("userId", FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Uid);

                query.Get().AddOnCompleteListener(this);

                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);
                    if (hasReadRecipes)
                        break;
                }

                return recipes;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return recipes;
            }
        }
```

And this is the whole Firestore Script if that helps solving it:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Tasks;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.Firestore;
using Food_Recipe_App.Assets.Classes;
using Food_Recipe_App.Helpers;
using Java.Interop;
using Java.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Food_Recipe_App.Droid.Dependencies.Auth))]
namespace Food_Recipe_App.Droid.Dependencies
{

    public class Firestore : Java.Lang.Object, IFirestore, IOnCompleteListener
    {
        List<Recipe> recipes;
        bool hasReadRecipes = false;

        public Firestore()
        {
            recipes = new List<Recipe>();
        }

        public async Task<bool> Delete(Recipe recipe)
        {
            try
            {
                var collection = FirebaseFirestore.Instance.Collection("recipes");
                collection.Document(recipe.Id).Delete();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> Insert(Recipe recipe)
        {
            try
            {
                var recipeDocument = new Dictionary<string, Java.Lang.Object>()
                {
                    { "title", recipe.title },
                    { "description", recipe.description },
                    { "creatorUserId", FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Uid }
                };

                var collection = Firebase.Firestore.FirebaseFirestore.Instance.Collection("recipes");
                collection.Add(new HashMap(recipeDocument));

                return true;
            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void OnComplete(Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task)
        {
            if (task.IsSuccessful)
            {
                var documents = (QuerySnapshot)task.Result;

                recipes.Clear();
                foreach (var doc in documents.Documents)
                {
                    Recipe newRecipe = new Recipe()
                    {
                        title = doc.Get("title").ToString(),
                        description = doc.Get("description").ToString(),
                        Id = doc.Id
                    };

                    recipes.Add(newRecipe);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                recipes.Clear();
            }

            hasReadRecipes = true;
        }

        public async Task<List<Recipe>> Read()
        {
            try
            {
                hasReadRecipes = false;
                var collection = FirebaseFirestore.Instance.Collection("recipes");

                var query = collection.WhereEqualTo("userId", FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Uid);

                query.Get().AddOnCompleteListener(this);

                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);
                    if (hasReadRecipes)
                        break;
                }

                return recipes;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return recipes;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> Update(Recipe recipe)
        {
            try
            {
                var recipeDocument = new Dictionary<string, Java.Lang.Object>()
                {
                    { "title", recipe.title },
                    { "description", recipe.description },
                    { "creatorUserId", FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Uid }
                };

                var collection = FirebaseFirestore.Instance.Collection("recipes");
                collection.Document(recipe.Id).Update(recipeDocument);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It breaks" - does this mean you get the null reference at this point?  Or the error about Guava?

Comment: So I realise maybe I made the post a little bit confusing. The error comes when I have Guava installed. It breaks when I don't have Guava installed, but I have no idea if Guava would fix the "breaking" since I haven't gotten it to start correctly.

Comment: what, specifically, is "the error" vs "breaks"?  What are the specific symptoms of each?  ie, **Scenario A**, I get this specific error message in this specific line of code.   **Scenario B** After I install package XYZ, the previous error goes away but now I get this specific error message on this specific line of code.

Comment: So Scenario A: I do not have the Guava package installed, I try to run my app but the code breaks. It breaks somewhere after calling the Firestore.Read(), after running this line: "var recipes = await Firestore.Read();". The message I get from this is "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'".

Scenario B: I'm trying to fix the issue of scenario one by installing Guava, which I've read could be a fix. But once installed I get the error saying "JAR library references with identical file names but different contents were found.

Comment: But I'm thinking it breaks after that line in Scenario A. It says "there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code", as of what I read online, the tip about Guava, they said it was breaking because there was sometimes an issue with guava being installed incorrectly in the base package of Xamarin.

Comment: I'd suggest removing Guava and focusing on the original error.  First, determine which **specific** line causes the problem, then determine which **specific** object is null.  The stack trace on the exception object should help you pin down the specific line.  Note that a NullRef is one of the most common errors in C# and there are literally millions of articles, posts, videos, etc discussing how to debug one.

Comment: I notice that when Jason asked you to clarify what happened under which circumstance, you responded with "Scenario A: ... it breaks". That is ambiguous. If you mean "Scenario A: ... got NullReferenceException", then please say that. Use the exact error or exception that occurred.

Comment: He did say that scenario A was a NullRef

Comment: Soooo, I'm sorry if I've been a little lost while providing the information about my issue. After a lot of debugging and tracing the error and getting nowhere I started looking through the whole script and the ones associated with it. Turns out it was a typo xD. I had copied the line calling the Dependency services from another script I have so one word there was wrong. I was calling Dependencies.Auth instead of Dependencies.Firestore. But it all works now. Thanks a lot for the help and I'm sorry for wasting your time :)